# как запретить в phpstorm перетаскивание файлов на сервере?

Tags: phpstorm

как запретить в phpstorm перетаскивание файлов на сервере? Уже 10 раз исчезали файлы проекта - приходилось искать, куча нервов... А все из-за того, что случайно можно перетащить файлы и папки на удаленном сервере. Может кто подскажет, как заблокировать это действие? Или хотя бы делать это через подтверждение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File->Settings (Ctrl+Alt+S)->Appereance&BEhaivor->Appereance

Видим настройку Drag-n-Drop with ALT pressend only

Comment: Огромное спасибо, добрый человек!